# Mulesoft Groovy script permission denied when reading a script file

Tags: groovy, mulesoft

I have created a flow in Anypoint studio.
I want to execute a shell script I have saved. I am using an execute script component with Groovy. My Groovy code looks like this:

```
cmd = '${mule.home}'
"$cmd/apps/script_test/script.sh".execute().text
```

I have confirmed that the file is there however I keep getting access denied error whenever I run this:

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/AnypointStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.202104131253/mule/apps/script_test/script.sh": error=13, Permission denied
```

I have tried changing the file's permissions, even set it to 777 but I still am getting this error. Any ideas how I can get this to run?

Comment: You have to run `.sh` using `sh` , `bash` , or some other shell

Comment: It ran, thank you. Please post this as an answer and I will mark it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `.sh` using `sh` , `bash` , or some other shell.

This should work

```
"sh .../script.sh".execute().text
```

Comment: You can use `${app.home}` to avoid a fixed path.